# How to subtract integer from COUNT(*) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I have written the following My SQL query to obtain a result. However, the SQL is incorrectly formatted, or there is some syntactical error.

I know this would be a trivial question , but since I am new to this, can you please guide me where I am wrong?

```
SELECT round( 
           ( 
           SELECT pow(2,SELECT Count(*) 
           FROM   students - 1)) / 
         ( 
                SELECT pow(2, 
                       ( 
                              SELECT count(*) 
                              FROM   students)) - 1) * 
         ( 
                SELECT sum(aptitude) 
                FROM   students), 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Parenthesis is absent in the first pow function.

pow(2,SELECT Count(*) FROM students - 1)

Correct parenthesis like the following.

```
SELECT pow(2,(SELECT Count(*) FROM students)  - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong form clause position in first subselect

```
SELECT round( 
                ( SELECT pow(2, ( SELECT Count(*)  FROM   students )) -1) / 
                ( SELECT pow(2, ( SELECT count(*)  FROM   students )) - 1) * 
                ( SELECT sum(aptitude)  FROM students), 2 )
```